# Cannot login to web service using httpClient authentication and post

Tags: web-services, httpclient

I am using httpClient 4 to authenticate to axelor  and trying to call a web service.

The login URL is http://localhost:8082/login.jsp , I am using docker to deploy axelor in a seperate container.

First I will be posting to the login URL and the response cookies will be stored and will be used in the subsequent requests. This is the strategy that I have used. The code for the same is given below

```
public String callService(String jsonString, String endPoint) throws Exception{
        String LOGIN_URL="http://localhost:8082/login.jsp";
        String SECURED_URL="http://localhost:8082/ws/meta/models";
        CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("akhil", "akhil*123");
        provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).build();

        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore(); 
        HttpClientContext httpContext = HttpClientContext.create();
        httpContext.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(LOGIN_URL);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost,httpContext);
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if(statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            HttpResponse response2 = client.execute(new HttpGet(SECURED_URL),httpContext);
            System.out.println(response2.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response2.getEntity()));
        }else {

        }
        return "";
    }
```

This will return status code as 200 in first login, but in the next HttpGet request, it is being redirected to the login page.

What am I doing wrong here?

The axelor documentaion asks you to login as below : https://docs.axelor.com/adk/5.0/dev-guide/web-services/auth.html

The same is working perfectly fine with postman application, but I dont know why it is not working with httpClient in java

EntityUtils.toString(response2.getEntity())  will print the login page.

But expected result is a json of models as given below :

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "total": 480,
    "data": [
        "com.axelor.apps.account.db.Account",
        "com.axelor.apps.account.db.AccountChart",
        "com.axelor.apps.account.db.AccountClearance",
        "com.axelor.apps.account.db.AccountConfig",
        "com.axelor.apps.account.db.AccountEquiv",
.
.
.
```

I will share the log file along with this post for reference :::

```
2019-03-27 12:44:23.157 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : CookieSpec selected: default
2019-03-27 12:44:23.157 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : Cookie [version: 0][name: JSESSIONID][value: 9D09E72B8A1EB0890BB75739D92795EF][domain: localhost][path: /][expiry: null] match [localhost:8082/ws/meta/models]
2019-03-27 12:44:23.157 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache   : Auth cache not set in the context
2019-03-27 12:44:23.157 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection request: [route: {}->http://localhost:8082][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
2019-03-27 12:44:23.157 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection leased: [id: 3][route: {}->http://localhost:8082][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 2 of 2; total allocated: 2 of 20]
2019-03-27 12:44:23.157 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Opening connection {}->http://localhost:8082
2019-03-27 12:44:23.158 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] .i.c.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator : Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:8082
2019-03-27 12:44:23.158 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] .i.c.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator : Connection established 127.0.0.1:50304<->127.0.0.1:8082
2019-03-27 12:44:23.158 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Executing request GET /ws/meta/models HTTP/1.1
2019-03-27 12:44:23.159 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2019-03-27 12:44:23.159 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2019-03-27 12:44:23.159 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 >> GET /ws/meta/models HTTP/1.1
2019-03-27 12:44:23.159 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 >> Host: localhost:8082
2019-03-27 12:44:23.159 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2019-03-27 12:44:23.159 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.7 (Java/1.8.0_201)
2019-03-27 12:44:23.159 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 >> Cookie: JSESSIONID=9D09E72B8A1EB0890BB75739D92795EF
2019-03-27 12:44:23.159 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
2019-03-27 12:44:23.159 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 >> "GET /ws/meta/models HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.159 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 >> "Host: localhost:8082[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.159 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.160 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.7 (Java/1.8.0_201)[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.160 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 >> "Cookie: JSESSIONID=9D09E72B8A1EB0890BB75739D92795EF[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.160 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.160 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 >> "[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.162 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "HTTP/1.1 302 [\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.163 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "Server: nginx/1.15.9[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.163 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "Date: Wed, 27 Mar 2019 07:14:23 GMT[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.163 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.164 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.164 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "Location: /login.jsp[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.165 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.166 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 << HTTP/1.1 302 
2019-03-27 12:44:23.166 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 << Server: nginx/1.15.9
2019-03-27 12:44:23.166 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 << Date: Wed, 27 Mar 2019 07:14:23 GMT
2019-03-27 12:44:23.166 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 << Content-Length: 0
2019-03-27 12:44:23.166 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 << Connection: keep-alive
2019-03-27 12:44:23.166 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 << Location: /login.jsp
2019-03-27 12:44:23.166 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2019-03-27 12:44:23.166 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection [id: 3][route: {}->http://localhost:8082] can be kept alive indefinitely
2019-03-27 12:44:23.166 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-3: set socket timeout to 0
2019-03-27 12:44:23.166 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection released: [id: 3][route: {}->http://localhost:8082][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 2 of 2; total allocated: 2 of 20]
2019-03-27 12:44:23.167 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.a.h.i.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy   : Redirect requested to location '/login.jsp'
2019-03-27 12:44:23.167 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.a.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec     : Redirecting to 'http://localhost:8082/login.jsp' via {}->http://localhost:8082
2019-03-27 12:44:23.167 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : CookieSpec selected: default
2019-03-27 12:44:23.167 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : Cookie [version: 0][name: JSESSIONID][value: 9D09E72B8A1EB0890BB75739D92795EF][domain: localhost][path: /][expiry: null] match [localhost:8082/login.jsp]
2019-03-27 12:44:23.167 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache   : Auth cache not set in the context
2019-03-27 12:44:23.168 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection request: [route: {}->http://localhost:8082][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 2 of 2; total allocated: 2 of 20]
2019-03-27 12:44:23.168 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection leased: [id: 3][route: {}->http://localhost:8082][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 2 of 2; total allocated: 2 of 20]
2019-03-27 12:44:23.168 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-3: set socket timeout to 0
2019-03-27 12:44:23.168 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Executing request GET /login.jsp HTTP/1.1
2019-03-27 12:44:23.168 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2019-03-27 12:44:23.168 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2019-03-27 12:44:23.168 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 >> GET /login.jsp HTTP/1.1
2019-03-27 12:44:23.168 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 >> Host: localhost:8082
2019-03-27 12:44:23.168 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2019-03-27 12:44:23.168 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.7 (Java/1.8.0_201)
2019-03-27 12:44:23.168 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 >> Cookie: JSESSIONID=9D09E72B8A1EB0890BB75739D92795EF
2019-03-27 12:44:23.169 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
2019-03-27 12:44:23.169 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 >> "GET /login.jsp HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.169 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 >> "Host: localhost:8082[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.169 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.169 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.7 (Java/1.8.0_201)[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.169 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 >> "Cookie: JSESSIONID=9D09E72B8A1EB0890BB75739D92795EF[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.169 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.169 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 >> "[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.175 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "HTTP/1.1 200 [\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.175 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "Server: nginx/1.15.9[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.175 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "Date: Wed, 27 Mar 2019 07:14:23 GMT[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.175 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.176 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.176 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.176 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "Vary: Accept-Encoding[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.177 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "Content-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.178 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.178 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "413[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.178 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "[0x1f][0x8b][0x8][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x3][0xac]Vmo[0xdb]6[0x10][0xfe][0x9c][0xfc][0x8a][0xb]W[0xe4][0x5][0xa8][0xac][0xa4][0xe8][0x80]u[0x95][0xc][0x4]Y[0xb][0x14][0xd8][0xd0] m?[0xec]#%[0x9e],6[0x14])[0x90][0x94][0x1d]o[0xed][0xdf]Q[0x94],[0xd9]IV[0xc][0x98][0x1][$u[0xc7][0xbb][0xe7][0xee][0xb9];g'[0xbf]}[0xbc][0xf9][0xfc][0xe7][0xed];[0xa8]}[0xa3][0x96][0xc7]Y|[0x0]d5r[0xb1]<[0x6][0xfa]d[\r]z[0xe]e[0xcd][0xad]C[0x9f][0xb3][0xce]W[0xc9]/l[0xfe]J[0xf3][0x6]s[0xb6][0x96][0xb8]i[0x8d][0xf5][0xc]J[0xa3]=j[0x12][0xdd]H[0xe1][0xeb]\[0xe0]Z[0x96][0x98][0xf4][0x9b][0x97] [0xb5][0xf4][0x92][0xab][0xc4][0x95]\a~[0xb5][0xb8]|[0x9][\r][0x90]M[0xd7][0xcc][0x8f]:[0x87][0xb6][0xdf][0xf3][0x82][0xa4][0xb4]y[0xc2][0xde][0xca][0x98][0x95][0xc2][0x99]5m[0xbc][0xe5][0xda])[0xee]q[0x14]WR[0xdf][0x83]E[0x95]3W[0x93]ke[0xe7]A[0x92]w[0xc]j[0x8b]U[0xce]h[0x9d]V[0x9c][0xbc]3zA?{ZQBH[0xe7]S[0xde][0xb6]J[0x96][0xdc]K[0x12]Sf%[0xf5]b[0xf5][0x97]l[0x17][0xa5]sl[0xb8][0xdc]o[0x15][0xba][0x1a][0xd1][0xd3][0x15][0x99]+[0xad]l=8[[0xe6][0xec][0xdf][0xf4][0xbf]:[0xb6][0xcc][0xd2](Mj[0xe9][0x18][0xf1][0xac]0b[0xbb]<[0x8e][0xb1][0x17]r[\r][0xa5][0xe2][0xce][0xe5],[0x84][0x95]KM[0x81][0xa9]T'[0xc5][0xe0]-[0xe5]g&[0xd3]r[0x8d][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.178 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "z'[0x93]~[0xbd][0x93]zB.[0x9][0x16][0xd1]B/[0x98][0x8][0xac]x[0xa7][0x2][0x82][0x90][0xf4][0xf8][0xc9]d[0xb3][0x8a]@h[0x91][0xf2][0x7]T[0xc6].Z[0xbd]b[0x10]S[0xcb][0xae][0xde][0xbc]j[0x1f]f*YJ[0xce]L7<r-[0x9][0xd8]f[0xf2][0xe4]Uel[0x3]R[0xe4],z[0x1d][0xb6][0xc]x[0x19][0xa2][0x9d]3[0x6]D[0xbe][0xda][0xd0][0xdb][0xdb][0x8f][0x9f]>[0xef])[0xee][0x3][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.178 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "jI%Q[0x9][0x8a][0xea][0xc]A[0xc0]1[0xf7]B[0xea][0xb6][0xf3]Ik[0xb1]E=[0x85]p[0x80][0x1b]d[0x1d]Ec[0x8c]8[0x17]"![0xb6],39[0x9e]T[0x1c]*[0x9e][0xa0]^S$Z[0xa2]Y[0x96][0xca][0x90]C[0xd2]94JW[0xf5][0xb6][0xc0]o[[0xaa][0xe][0x8f][0xf]T[0x19][0x1]f[0xa0]v[0xa8][0x98][0xf][0x82]A[0xac][0x9c][0xf1][0x84]A[0xab]x[0x89][0xb5]Q[0x94][0x95][0x9c]}[0x19][0x4])[0x1a][0x9d]7[0x95]);"[0xc1]n[0xf9][0x18][0xe5]~[0xe8]#[0xa4][0xff][0x1d][0xba]2[0xe5][0xfd][0x80][0xdd][0x12]s7[0xc6][0x12][0xd4][0x0]}[0xdc]M[0xd0][0xc7][0x93][0x3][0xe8][0xb7][0xa3][0xda]aT[0xf][0xf8]5[0x80]T[0xbc] [0xd6][0xf]e"[0xb]3g[0xe4][0x98][0xda][0xbd]l[0x94]5[0x96][0xf7]A[0xe][0xd6]\u[0x94][0x1e][0x8b][\r]6[0x5][0xda]?[0xa8][0xa1][0xc4][0xa4][0xcc]N[0xe][0x9d]8`Io[0xef]Y[0x12][0xcc][0xf9][0xe4][0xa5][0xa7][0x8e][0xb5][0xbc][0x1b][0x8c][0x11][0xb7][0x9f]V[0xcb][0xd2][0x1e][0xd1][0xbe][0xdd]'[0xa0][0xcf][0xb3][0x1b][0xb][0xc0][0x18][0x8f][0xf6]15[0x8a][0xce]{[0xb3][0xa3]u[0xe1]5[0xd0][0x97][0xaa]@6[0xdc]n[0xd9]@Q[0xd7][0x15][0x8d][0xa4][0xfa][0xff][0xdd][0xac][0xa8]KgiT[0xfa][0x81][0x13]Y[0x1a][0xc]OB{^[0xee]oB[0x9b][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.179 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << ",(l[0xb2][0xe1]V[0xcb][0xd0]F[0x86][0x9c][0xd1]([0xb0][0x1e][0xfa][0xdf][0xa4][0x8][0x14][0x1b][0xd6]h[0xad][0xb1]PK![0x90][0xca][0xf0][0xf8][0x8][0xe0]([0xab]_/[0xbf][0xb4][0x82][0x9a]<lMg[0xa1][0xb0]fC[0x85]rB[0xfd][0xf3][0xf5] [0xd1][0xd1] [0xb][0xa2]G[0x99][0x92][0xcb][0x9b][0xda][0x9a][0x10]gZN[0x87][0xef]%[0xf5][0xf3]pp[0xfa][0x89]W[0xdc][0xca][0x83][0xc3][0xf][0xef]`[0x99][0xc3][0xd5][0xd5]t[0x9c][0xa5][0x83][0x81][0x1][0x1e][0x99][0xea][0x13][0x11][0xb0]q[0xf1][0xc][0xb6]G[0x18][0xae]E[0xf][0x94][0xda][0xaf]@[0x8f][0xa5]G1[0x83]p[0xab][0x90];[0x4][0x9a][0x1e]a[0xfe][0x81][0xaf][0x11][0xf8]N[0x9e];[0x90][0x9e][0x86][0xe6][0x16][0x9c]2[0x1b][0x10]f[0xa3][0xa3][0xc4]lL[0xcd]"?,[0xe3]8[0xa9]z[0x82][0x8c]av[0xa2][0xb4];[0x9][0x8b][0x82][0x8c][0xb9][0x86]+[0xc5][0x96][0xa7][0xa5]i[0xb7]o[0xe1][0xd5][0xe5][0xe5][0xcf][0x90][0xd0][0xe3][0xea][\r]\[0xc7][0x99][0x0][0xd7]J[0xc1][0x9d]\[0xd5][0xde][0xc1][0x1d]R>[0xd6]([0x16]Y[0xda]Fb[0x4][0x92][0x4]b[0xc6][0xdd]4[0xd8]b[0xc4][0xfa]8[0x84][0x9e][0xd2][0x8f][0x8e][0xf8]v[0x98][0xa1]S[0xef]L[0xbf][0xf2]5[0x8f][0xa7][0x3][0xbd]_[0x9c]W[0x9d][0xee][0xc7][0x4][0x9c]_[0xc0][0xdf]![0xb9][0x0][0xb2][0x82][0xf3]aL[\r][0xc4]X4N"[0x9c][0x9e][0xc2][0xc9][0xc1][0xb9]][0xef][0xb4][0x8e]^[0x9c][0x9f][0xfd]4[0xd1][0xf2][0xec]bA[0xd5]o[0xd6]x[0x13][0x6][0xef][0xf9]Y[0xcc][0xdd][0xd9][0xc5][0xdb]h[0xe3][0xfb]d*[0xe8][\r][0x89]9[0xbb][0x80]<[0xcf][0xa1][0xd3]4GiH[0xb][0xf8][0xf6][\r][0xf6]^/$][0xf5][0xeb]x[0xd7][0xbe][0xed][0x89]6?[0xb4][0x1d]P~'W[0xc2]s[0xfa][0xf7][0x10][0xd6][0xf1]o[0x3][0xd5]A[0xff]O[0xee][0x1f][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xff][0xff][\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.179 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "a[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.179 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "[0x3][0x0][0x13]7[0xbc]S[0xda][0x9][0x0][0x0][\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.179 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "0[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.179 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-3 << "[\r][\n]"
2019-03-27 12:44:23.179 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 << HTTP/1.1 200 
2019-03-27 12:44:23.179 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 << Server: nginx/1.15.9
2019-03-27 12:44:23.179 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 << Date: Wed, 27 Mar 2019 07:14:23 GMT
2019-03-27 12:44:23.179 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 << Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
2019-03-27 12:44:23.179 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2019-03-27 12:44:23.180 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 << Connection: keep-alive
2019-03-27 12:44:23.180 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 << Vary: Accept-Encoding
2019-03-27 12:44:23.180 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-3 << Content-Encoding: gzip
2019-03-27 12:44:23.180 DEBUG 19732 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
```

Comment: Finally figured it out : Axelor wanted the credentials to be provided as request body. In the above example with AuthenticationProvider you would be posting the credentials in the request header. The response status code (200) made me confuse that it was logged in the initial post request. i will post the changed code as the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axelor wanted the credentials to be provided as request body. In the above example with AuthenticationProvider you would be posting the credentials in the request header. The response status code (200) made me confuse that it was logged in the initial post request.

The changed code is as below :

```
public String callService(String jsonString, String endPoint) throws Exception{
        String LOGIN_URL="http://localhost:8082/login.jsp";
        String SECURED_URL="http://localhost:8082/ws/meta/models";
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); //Use this instead 

        try {

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(LOGIN_URL);
            StringEntity params =new StringEntity("{\"username\":\"admin\",\"password\":\"admin\"} ");
            httpPost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            httpPost.setEntity(params);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(SECURED_URL);
            HttpResponse response2 = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            System.out.println(response2.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response2.getEntity()));
        }catch (Exception ex) {

            //handle exception here

        } finally {
            //Deprecated
            //httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); 
        }   
        return "";
    }
```